# MySQL: Relacionar 5 tablas LEFT JOIN y COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, join, count

Tengo 5 tablas:

- Tabla `usuarios`:

  ```
  | id_usuario | nombre_usuario  |
  | ---------- | --------------- |
  | 1          | jose perez      |
  | 2          | manolo garcia   |
  | 3          | antonio sanchez |
  ```
- Tabla `productos`:

  ```
  | id_producto | nombre_producto   |
  | ----------- | ----------------- |
  | 1           | camiseta espinete |
  | 2           | camiseta batman   |
  | 3           | camiseta simpson  |
  ```
- Tabla `favoritos`:

  ```
  | id_favoritos | id_producto | id_usuario |
  | ------------ | ----------- | ---------- |
  | 1            | 3           | 2          |
  | 2            | 1           | 3          |
  | 3            | 2           | 1          |
  ```
- Tabla `chistes`:

  ```
  | id_chiste | titulo_chiste    |
  | --------- | ---------------- |
  | 1         | chiste arevalo   |
  | 2         | chiste jose mota |
  | 3         | chiste gatos     |
  ```
- Tabla `likes`:

  ```
  | id_like | id_chiste | id_usuario |
  | ------- | --------- | ----  ---- |
  | 1       | 3         | 2          |
  | 2       | 1         | 3          |
  | 3       | 2         | 1          |
  ```

Donde un usuario puede añadir productos como favoritos y darle like a los chistes. Me interesa conocer la cantidad total de favoritos y likes de cada usuario en una misma consulta y ordenar la lista de usuarios por una u otra cantidad (cantidad de favoritos o cantidad de likes, según lo que se seleccione). Se como hacerlo por separado, es decir, en dos consultas diferentes:

- Para listar los usuarios con el número total de favoritos uso:

```
SELECT usuarios.*,
count(favoritos.id_usuario) AS numFavoritos
FROM usuarios
LEFT JOIN favoritos 
ON usuarios.id_usuario = favoritos.id_usuario
GROUP BY usuarios.id_usuario
ORDER BY numFavoritos DESC
```

- Y para listar los usuarios con el número total de likes uso:

```
SELECT usuarios.*,
count(likes.id_usuario) AS numLikes
FROM usuarios
LEFT JOIN likes 
ON usuarios.id_usuario = likes.id_usuario
GROUP BY usuarios.id_usuario
ORDER BY numLikes DESC
```

He estado probando para hacerlo en una única consulta a la base de datos, pero no lo consigo.
Si alguien pudiera ayudar, se lo agradecería muchísimo, un saludo a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la cantidad de favoritos y de likes puedes unir las tres tablas de este modo:

```
SELECT 
    usuarios.*,
    count(favoritos.id_usuario) AS numFavoritos,
    count(likes.id_usuario) AS numLikes
FROM usuarios
    LEFT JOIN favoritos ON usuarios.id_usuario = favoritos.id_usuario
    LEFT JOIN likes ON usuarios.id_usuario = likes.id_usuario
GROUP BY usuarios.id_usuario
ORDER BY numFavoritos DESC, numLikes DESC
```

Si te interesa ordenar primero por likes sólo tienes que cambiar la parte del orden así:

```
ORDER BY numLikes DESC, numFavoritos DESC
```